# Let $f(x)$ be a linear function such that $f(0) = -5$ and $f(f(0)) = -15$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $f(x)$ be a linear function such that $f(0) = -5$ and $f(f(0)) = -15$. Find all values of $m$ such that the solutions of $f(x)f(m-x) > 0$ are of the form of an interval of length $2$.

**What I Tried** :- As $f(0) = -5$ , I know that $f(-5) = -15$ .
How does this help, if I am trying to find an interval of length $2$ in the case of $f(x)f(m-x) > 0$ ?

I can put $x = 0$ or $x = -5$ , but in that case I only get $-5f(m) > 0$ or $-15f(m + 15) > 0$ . In both the cases we get $f(m)$ and $f(m + 5)$ are negative, anything else useful?

Also I only know the value of $f(0)$ and $f(-5)$, what about $f(1),f(2)$ and so on?

Can anyone help me understand this? Most Probably I didn't get the question.

Comment: If it's a linear function it's uniquely determined with two points i. e with $f(0)=-5,f(-5)=-15$.

Comment: Ok, but why so? Can you explain more? I can take $f(x) = ax + b$ as it is linear

Comment: @Anonymous Now determine $a$ and $b$ such that $f(0)=-5$ and $f(-5)=15$

Comment: Oh, $b = -5$ and $a = 2$, is that it?

Comment: Oh I think I got the solutions, thank you @HagenvonEitzen for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so from @HagenvonEitzen's Hint I think I got the solution.

As $f(x)$ is a linear function, let $f(x) = ax + b$ . Then :-
$f(0) = b$

$\rightarrow b = -5$

Similarly I get :-
$f(f(0)) = -15$

$\rightarrow f(-5) = -15$

$\rightarrow -5a + b = -15$

$\rightarrow a = 2$

Now from here I have :- $$f(x)f(m - x) > 0$$
$$\rightarrow (2x - 5)(2(m-x) - 5) > 0$$
$$\rightarrow (2x - 5)(2x + 5 - 2m) < 0$$

So $m$ lies between $\frac{5}{2}$ and $\frac{2m - 5}{2}$ , having an interval $2$ .
So :- $$\frac{5}{2} - \frac{2m - 5}{2} = 2$$
$$\rightarrow m = 3$$

And :- $$\frac{2m - 5}{2} - \frac{5}{2} = 2$$
$$\rightarrow m = 7$$

So I think these are the $2$ solutions.

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I do something wrong? Please correct me if I did.